# How to specify which DIR is to be used by haystack and whoosh during index-building

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

I am trying to index my `MySQL` Data into `Whoosh` using `Haystack` But as my root partition is almost Full is their any way to specify which DIR to be used by `Haystack and Whoosh` during indexing data. As it uses `/tmp/` DIR during this process how can i change that DIR to something else.. I know best way is to increase the root partition But i am looking for an alternative ....

Comment: If you check the [documentation](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#whoosh) you can see there is `PATH` settings. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: No, that path is for `whoosh_index DIR under Django project DIR` .. Actually when you run `rebuild_index` command it uses `/tmp/ Dir` and i want to change that DIR to something else ..

Answer (score 0):

I found this setting.. maybe it helps you:

```
WHOOSH_STORAGE_DIR = '/data/whoosh'
```

Apart from that, I found [a script snippet](http://pastebin.com/F9SzA729) where you might change the '/tmp/' directory.

*I am not familiar with those projects.. I just thought I might share what I found.* ;)